# Multiprocessing in python, work with several files

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have done a script to convert several files simultaneously, but instead of converting 4 files together with several processes, the code converts files one by one with several processes, here's my code:

```
def convert (directoryName):
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directoryName):
    for f in files:
      if f.endswith(".txt")
        f1=f
        path1=path         
        p=mp.Process(target=convert1, args=(path1,f1,))
  p.start()
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: it's stange that you're calling `p.start()` outside the loop. So only last `p` created is started.

Comment: Maybe it worked because I had only one file, I'll try with several files and I'll give you the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code overwrites `p` everytime, so you only start 1 process when your loop is finished.

Instead, call `p.start` when you create the process, and store it so you can call `join` on all processes in the end:

```
def convert (directoryName):
  process_list = []
  for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directoryName):
    for f in files:
      if f.endswith(".txt")
        f1=f
        path1=path         
        p=mp.Process(target=convert_stdf_hdf5, args=(path1,f1,))
        p.start()
        process_list.append(p)
  # wait for processes to finish
  for p in process_list:
     p.join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your code step by step, but it seems that the function convert is not executed. Is it because I didn't set if __name__ == '__main__':?

Comment: oh yes, on windows you need to put that in `if __name__=="__main__"` because of a shady process duplication issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using starmap. (Python3.3 or later.)

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def convert(directoryName):
    p = Pool()
    args = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directoryName):
        args.extend([[path, f] for f in files if f.endswith('.txt')])
    p.starmap(convert_stdf_hdf5, args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    convert('path/to/target/')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I use the 2.7. But thank you very much, I hope it will help those who will look at this post.